# Render static file ASP.NET outside ASP.NET pipeline

Tags: asp.net

i have an ASP.NET application and there are a few pages I would like to process outside ASP.NET pipeline, such as index.html in other words treat is as a static file.

is there a way to do this? like a web.config setting.

thanks in advance.

ashwin

Comment: please be more clear - I did not understand what is your issue. Who and how what is "render" ? do you mean compile ? from where ?

Comment: please review description, in other words i meant does .html pages have to go via ASP.NET page cycle?

Comment: html did not go via asp.net page cycle, except if you have declare it on iis extensions.

Comment: how would i know that on shared hosting?

Comment: add some asp.net code and see if they are compile